# how to interactively control the animation in powerpoint?

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

I am creating a slide to demonstrate something like the first animation in this page http://www.colorado.edu/physics/2000/bec/what_is_it.html, I don't know much about animation in swf but I know some idea how to create an interactive and animated PDF. But when I embed the pdf into slide, it only shown the "image" of the pdf or really embed a pdf viewer and shown the pdf inside the viewer. I am looking for different way to create an interactive animation like the one I show above. But after googling for some times, I didn't see any. I am thinking to draw that with VBA but I don't know what to start. So is there any example or instruction how to draw the graph with VBA dynamically or do you have any better idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could always leave that kind of stuff to the design experts. It's a task organizing complex information into appealing graphics for your audience. Getting custom slide design service may save a lot of time. Or just browse pre-designed, [animated Powerpoint templates](http://www.slideshop.com/powerpoint-animations) for the one that suits your presentation needs most.